# How do you test php code on my local computer (Ubuntu)?

Tags: php, mysql, html, webserver

I was reading my new php and MySQL book and it said that if I had a "web server installed locally and it has PHP support, then you can test out PHP scripts directly on yout computer." How do I get all this on linux and once I have it how do I test if my php scripts are working?

Comment: You might get better answers on serverfault.com

Comment: @jeroen and the others who migrated this to SF. It's just as OT there as it was here. SF is for people who manage system, desktop infrastructure, networks etc which this clearly isn't about.

Comment: @Iain It is? I thought that was the place for server installation / configuration / problems as well...

Comment: @jeroen: This should have just been closed OT - it shows no research effort... If it had to go somewhere then SU is a better home for it.

Comment: @Iain Agreed about the research effort, not sure I've got the distinction between SF and SU right :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a LAMP stack. Since you already have Ubuntu, an AMP stack.
`sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-mysql` from the command line will set you up a web server with php. Then, you can put your scripts in /var/www/